# If i want the JDK for my Mac, where should I look for it?

Tags: java, macos

I want Java to be installed on my Leopard MacBook, but I couldn't find the JDK kit for Mac on Sun's Java site.  Where should I look for it?

Comment: For OSX Lion - 10.7 - neither java nor jdk come pre-installed, in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JDK is already installed on Mac OS X 10.5.  If you go to /Applications/Utilities you will see Java Preferences.  There you can select between the versions of Java you would like to use, including version 6 (6 is only 64-bit so if you have a 32-bit Core Duo Macbook you'll have to use [SoyLatte](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/)).

[alt text http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/4249/javapref.jpg](http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/4249/javapref.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the [Xcode developer tools](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html). The JDK is included there. Before you do that, though, you can check if it is already installed by using `javac -version`. To find out where it is located, you can run the command `which javac`, although it will most likely be a symlink to somewhere else.

Comment: I think the JDK is installed even without the dev tools.

Comment: @Thilo, thanks. I'm not sure, that's why I pointed him to check.

Comment: Even with dev tools, you need to install the API docs separately. http://developer.apple.com/ or http://developers.sun.com/downloads/

Comment: @trashgod, who wants to waste the space for that? IMHO, the online docs are good enough: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Comment: I prefer online, but I also keep local copies for the IDEs and a set under version control for notes & links. The downside: I sometimes post links that start file:/// :-)

Comment: You do NOT need to install Xcode in order to get the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

It comes with the OS.

Try "java -version" in Terminal.

Apple is maintaining this version, not Sun. It gets updated using Software Update, and there may be downloads (for beta versions) at the Apple Developer Connection site.

Comment: "java" is part of the JRE, not the JDK. To check the JDK version, use "javac -version"

Comment: Java is also part of the JDK, it may simply redirect to ../jre/bin/java, but it's added.

Comment: On 10.12, Java --version will route you to the JDK download site if not installed already.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/) seems to be the ultimate source for anyone who doesn't want to run in to licensing issues. I understand Oracle's version is derived from OpenJDK.

Installers for macOS can be found at https://adoptopenjdk.net/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [soylatte](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/) or openJDK from Mac Ports . Also, Apple has download section of java too ( http://developer.apple.com/java/download/ )
you didn't tell what architecture you are using which has some impact.